# Deleting lines with sed , unknown command error

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I am trying to delete 4 subsequent lines on a pattern match.
The pattern to match is something I am reading line by line from other file.

My script looks like this:

```
#! /bin/bash     

while read line; do
    cat database.US_en_test | sed "/$line/ , +4d"  >> output 
done < file_del.txt
```

However, I am getting an error like :

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unknown command: `1'
```

Not sure what the error is, please help!

Comment: Add content of file_del.txt.

Comment: As @cyrus alluded, there may be a line in file_del.txt that has a `/` character in it.  Showing us that file might help.  Also, if you add `set -x` before the loop bash will print each line with variables expanded before executing it so you'll be able to see exactly what the `sed` command looks like when it fails

Answer (score 0):

The only character that can cause error in an address is an extra `/` in the pattern.

With GNU sed, you can use another character as delimiter : choose one you know sed won't find in your file_del.txt and prefix the first delimiter with a backslash in your address :

```
sed "\_$line_, +4d"
```